# Inet_ntoa over a whole column of a database

Tags: mysql

I have a table (`sessions`) in a database whose 1st column contain numeric ip addresses like:

```
_____________
| srcIP     |
-------------
| 167973143 |
| 167973187 |
| 167971450 |
-------------
```

To display IP addresses i am using following query

```
mysql> select srcIP from sessions;
```

I should use INET_NTOA to get the dotted ip addresses but what should be the query for displaying the whole column with dotted ip addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(srcIP) FROM sessions
```

see [`INET_NTOA(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) and the corresponding [`INET_ATON(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)

Answer (score 0):

Found this for example: inet_ntoa() - Convert IP addresses from a dots-and-number string to a struct in_addr and back

What you need is a function that converts the converted of IP-addresses back to the dotted form. which function you will need for this depends on the programming language you use - it CAN NOT BE DONE IN SQL itself!

In PHP you'll probably want to use long2ip()...

Answer (score 0):

Stefan Gehrig's answer is obviously better in MySQL, but in general, you can use:

```
select cast((srcIp/16777216) & 255 as varchar) + '.'
    + cast((srcIp/65536) & 255 as varchar) + '.'
    + cast((srcIp/256) & 255 as varchar) + '.'
    + cast(srcIp & 255 as varchar)
from sessions
```

to convert from a number to an IPv4 address.